# Making Selections Happen by Rows in Verbatim (or alternative)

Tags: verbatim

I am using the verbatim package to display data in an SI (specifically, a molecular geometry). When I create the pdf and try to select the data, it selects by columns instead of rows:

[image: Undesired selection behavior]

When I try to paste the data, it pastes everything in columns, destroying the organization. What can I do to allow selection and pasting to keep the inherent order of the data? I've tried tabular, but got the same result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
a   1   2   3
b   4   5   6
c   7   8   9
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post the source code too; or rather, a reduced version of it that still suffices to demontrate the issue (_i.e._, a Minimal Working Example).  As far as I know, the contents of a `verbatim` environment are processed one line at a time.

Comment: that's very weird, can you try the same pdf with other viewers?

Comment: It seems somewhat dependent on the pdf viewer. Evince (the defualt in Ubuntu) shows the above behavior, Okular is too ambitious and continues to select outside of the current column if using multicols, the Chrome and Firefox pdf viewers work as expected, Qpdfview fails, Xpdf fails. Is there a workaround that works on all pdf viewers?

Comment: Indeed, I cannt reproduce the issue either.  I’m on a Mac, I’ve compiled your code and opened the resulting PDF file in Acrobat Reader, Preview, Skim, and TeXShop, and in all of them selection occurs by rows.  The pdfTeX compiler should store the strings in the output file in an order that reflects the order in which they were processed

Comment: there probably isn't much you can do, pdf is adding those characters by row but viewers have heuristics to spot multi-column layouts which seem to be defeating you here. that is they are over-trying to avoid the behaviour that you describe for okular

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is viewer-dependent and *there probably isn't much you can do* (@DavidCarlisle).

Comment: Both Adobe Reader and SumatraPDF copies by-row, not by-column.